# Spring Cloud Data Flow, failed to follow HTTP to MySQL Demo

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am new to Spring Cloud Data Flow. Just trying to follow the official demo [HTTP to MySQL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_http_to_mysql_demo) I created a MySQL database (ds_dev) and a table (names) with:

```
create table names
(
  name  varchar(255) null
);
```

I followed the instructions to create a stream with:

```
stream create --name mysqlstream --definition "http --server.port=9010 | jdbc --tableName=names --columns=name --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --spring.datasource.url='jdbc:mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/ds_dev' --spring.datasource.username=root --spring.datasource.password='rootpw'" --deploy
```

Then I tried to post some requests with :

```
http post --contentType 'application/json' --target http://172.18.0.5:9010 --data "{\"name\": \"Foo\"}"
```

However, instead of having a new entry "Foo" inserted into the table, I got a Null value inserted instead. The jdbc log is like this:

```
2019-08-06 19:10:10.838  INFO 598 --- [container-0-C-1] o.s.c.s.a.j.sink.JdbcSinkConfiguration   : Could not find value for column 'name': EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'byte[]' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see in the sample, though, it, unfortunately, points to an older release. It is pointing to a link that results in 404 as well - sorry about that.

Please clean-slate the demo environment and retry with the latest Einstein apps. We have had some issue on the JDBC-sink after Spring Cloud Stream 2.x upgrade, and that has been resolved in the recent releases.

Latest Einstein Apps for Kafka: http://dataflow.spring.io/kafka-maven-latest

*(more details in the [reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_cloud_stream_app_starters))*

We will fix the bogus URIs in the samples via: [spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples#117](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/issues/117).

Comment: Hi Sabby, thanks for the reply. I would like to try out Einstein Apps but I don't know where to start. Will there be an update on the tutorials for simple tasks like HTTP to MySQL? Thanks

Comment: Yes, the sample is already updated. The PR has been merged. The latest docs can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_http_to_mysql_demo).

Comment: To be clear, you would import the latest apps through this URI: http://dataflow.spring.io/kafka-maven-latest

Comment: Great! It works after dataflow:>app import --uri https://dataflow.spring.io/kafka-maven-latest   and then selecting the latest JDBC app as default. Thanks for your help!